# Azure APIM URL throws System.Net.WebException - How SSL/TLS making difference in azure web api and azure APIM?

Tags: c#, azure, ssl, asp.net-web-api, azure-api-management

I have created `web api` and tried to issue `GET` request using `c#` as follow

```
namespace APIMCheck
{
 class Program
 {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string thumbprint = "***"; 
        string url @"https://******-us-stats-webapi.azurewebsites.net/statistics/v1/masterData/carTypes";


        X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

        X509Certificate2Collection certificates = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbprint, true);
        X509Certificate2 certificate = certificates[0];
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AcceptAllCertifications);

        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);


        req.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);
        req.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;

        Console.WriteLine(Program.CallAPI(req).ToString());

        Console.Read();

    }

    public static string CallAPI(HttpWebRequest req)
    {
        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }

    public static bool AcceptAllCertifications(object sender, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certification, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain, System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        return true;
    }
  }
}
```

I get response with data. All good.

Now, I have created `Azure APIM`, which will act as front end for above `web API`

This is policy configured in Azure API Management portal

```
<policies>
  <inbound>
    <base />
      <choose>
        <when condition="@(context.Request.Certificate.Verify() != true || context.Request.Certificate == null || context.Request.Certificate.Issuer != "CN=MySubCA, DC=MYEXT, DC=NET" || context.Request.Certificate.NotAfter < DateTime.Now)">
            <return-response>
                <set-status code="403" reason="Invalid client certificate" />
                <set-body template="none">@(context.Request.Certificate.Issuer.ToString())</set-body>
            </return-response>
        </when>
    </choose>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
     <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
     <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
     <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

Now, changed the `url` as follow to point `apim`

```
 string url = @"https://******-us-stats-apim.azure-api.net/statistics/v1/masterData/carTypes";
```

I get below error

> The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel for HttpWebRequest

How SSL/TLS making difference in web api and APIM?

Anything to do with firewall?

Answer (score 1):

**By default, TLS 1.2 is enabled for Azure API Management gateway**.

You could go to your azure api management(on portal) > `Protocol settings`> turn on `tls 1.2` and `ssl 3.0`.

[image]

Comment: I could turn on SSL 3.0 but TLS 1.2 is disabled

Comment: The TLS 1.2 is disable?  What about TLS 1.1?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you do in your test app and APIM cannot do on it's own:

1. Enable SSL3
2. Add client certificate
3. Ignore any SSL validation errors.

Of the things above only #2 is fine to have in production. SSL3 is deprecated and should not be used in production. Ignoring any SSL errors is also unwise, since that way you cannot be sure that you're talking to your server.

Now assuming that you're fine with all of the above:

1. For SSL3 follow @Joey Cai answer.
2. To allow APIM to use your certificate to authenticate to backend follow this guidance: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-mutual-certificates
3. To control SSL validation at APIM level use this REST API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/2019-01-01/backend/createorupdate and [set-backend-service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#SetBackendService) policy.

The main reason for #2 and #3 is that client-to-APIM and APIM-to-backend are two separate connections. So when APIM needs to make a call to backend it must have client certificate available (if it's required by backend). That also means that by default APIM will not require client to provide certificate.